# Can "sequi" be used to indicate that I "follow" an argument?

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

I would like to know if [*sequor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsequor) can be used to translate a sentence like the following:

> Do you follow my argument?

The linked L&S entry does not have anything equivalent, though it does indicate logical uses like "ensues," as in the common phrase "non sequitur."

If it can't be used in this way, what would be a better way to translate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a wide choice of verbs for your purpose, but *sequor* isn't one of them : it has more a sense of 'pursue', so you might more properly use it for 'pursue an argument' — or a theory, for example — yourself, rather than for following another's line of reasoning.

The sense that you are looking for is synonymous with 'understand' or 'grasp', for which either *intellego*  or *comprehendo* would do quite well : however these really mean to take in something mentally, for which *capio* would serve equally. For the precise sense that I take from your question (and for myself, in fact, in most cases) I should prefer to use *complector*, with its slightly wider sense of both embracing and accepting. However, the differences between these are pretty slight, and the best choice depends, as ever, on actual context.